# How to convert sql limit query to linq lambda?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

Here's an example that I want to convert to lambda query:

```
SELECT TOP(5) Pbschedules.s_id, Pbschedules.date, Pbworth2.worth, Pbschedules.pb_id 
FROM Pbschedules INNER JOIN Pbworth2 ON Pbschedules.pb_id = Pbworth2.pb_id
ORDER BY s_id desc
```

Comment: You can use `Take(5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = database.Pbschedules// your starting point - table in the "from" statement
  .Join(database.Pbworth2, // the source table of the inner join
  pbs=> pbs.pb_id,        // Select the primary key (the first part of the "on" clause in an sql "join" statement)
  worth=> worth.pb_id,   // Select the foreign key (the second part of the "on" clause)
  (pbs, worth) => new { PbsID = pbs.s_id, Worth = worth.worth /*other columns*/ }) // selection
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.s_id)      
  .Take(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myData = (from valuesPbs in Pbschedules join valuesPbw in Pbworth2
              on valuesPbs.pb_id equals valuesPbw.pb_id 
              orderby valuesPbs.s_id descending
              select valuesPbs
             ).Take(5);
```